# "ExpiresDefault access" vs. "ExpiresDefault access plus zero seconds"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, http-headers, httpd.conf

In an Apache config file or a .htaccess file, is there any difference between `ExpiresDefault "access"` and `ExpiresDefault "access plus zero seconds"`?

Are they the exactly the same?

Is the second one even valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one should say `0` instead of `zero`.

From the manual:

The ExpiresDefault and ExpiresByType directives can also be defined in a more readable syntax of the form:

```
ExpiresDefault "<base> [plus] {<num> <type>}*"
ExpiresByType type/encoding "<base> [plus] {<num> <type>}*"
```

where `<base>` is one of:

```
access
now (equivalent to 'access')
modification
```

The 'plus' keyword is optional. `<num>` should be an integer value [acceptable to atoi()], and `<type>` is one of:

```
years
months
weeks
days
hours
minutes
seconds
```

`ExpiresDefault "access plus zero seconds"` has probably been used where the author at one point had a time addition there and forgot that 0 isn't the same as zero!

Comment: I take it that the asterisk at the end of the syntax definition means "0 or more times" and that the curly braces mean that it is `num` and `type` taken together as a unit that must appear 0 or more times.  Oddly, the asterisk and curly braces are not explained at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax.  And based on that, I might think "0 or more times" would be written as "[whatever] ..."

Comment: Yep, that's right. The example they give is ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month 15 days 2 hours", showing how you can repeat the num type bit. I think the * means multiple times, and the {} mean optional unit. Assumedly [] means optional part, and <> means compulsory... Would be nice if they explained that!

Comment: Looks like the documentation could use some small but important clarifications.  I've submitted a bug for it:  https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52112